# Exibir um alerta quando faltar 5 minutos para o evento

Tags: java, javafx, time, agendamento

Estou desenvolvendo uma agenda em Java, onde tenho no banco de dados a data e o horário salvos. Porém, qual seria a melhor maneira de exibir um alerta 5 minutos antes do evento? Tenho que ficar rodando o método de consulta toda hora até os horários baterem? Ou tem uma maneira mais simples de se fazer isso?

Comment: não seria melhor uma notificação ou quer mesmo um alert?

Comment: pode ser uma notificação também. O problema é como vou ficar verificando a hora. Vou ter que fazer um método pra buscar no banco toda hora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Techies**

Você pode utilizar um `Timer (java.util.Timer)` e programar ele para executar 5 minutos antes de sua hora:

```
private Timer timer;

private void programaPara(Date data){// mande a data com 5 minutos de antecedência.

       timer = new Timer();

       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               //faça algo
           }
      }, data);
   }
```

Para subtrair 5 minutos da data você pode estar utilizando o `Calendar`:

```
public Date getDataMenos5Minutos(Date data){
     Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTime(data);
     calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);

     return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Valeu cara, fiz uma task que faz uma verificação na minha lista de 1 em 1 minuto

Comment: Opa. Já fiz uma aplicação parecida. No meu caso eu pesquisava todas do banco para determinado dia, e então criava um `task` com alerta para cada uma encontrada, e então quando dava a hora essa `task` executava a ação da minha classe.